# A helix winding around the z-axis

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors

Why is the z component of the position vector in the following equation is defined by $at\boldsymbol k$ ? Doesn't that describe velocity? I would assume that the right form would look something like: $z_0 + v_zt$, letting k unit vector define the direction on the z axis. What am I getting wrong here?

[image]

Source: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-vectors-and-matrices/part-c-parametric-equations-for-curves/session-17-general-parametric-equations-the-cycloid/MIT18_02SC_notes_9.pdf

Comment: The two things look the same to me if you assume $z_0$ is zero and $a = v_z$

Comment: How can $at$ be equal to $vt$ ?

Comment: They're just letters.  $a$ here does not mean acceleration.  This text is coming from a mathematics point of view, not a physics/mechanics point of view.

Comment: Oh, geez. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider the curve
$$R(t) = r_0 cos(t) i + r_0 sin(t)j + atk$$

Suppose $a = 0$. Then you have a point following a circle in the $z = 0$ plane at uniform speed.

Suppose instead that $r_0 = 0$. Then you have a point following the $z$ axis at uniform speed.

If you set $r_0 = 1$, you combine these two motions. The curve follows a circle that climbs uniformly. Every turn is higher than the previous by the same distance.

Comment: But isn't there a difference between $z_0+v_zt$ and  $at\boldsymbol k$ while defining the position vector along the z-axis? The latter looks like velocity to me.

Comment: Set $r_0 = 0$. Then $\vec v = \frac{d \vec R}{dt} = a \vec k$. You can do a similar calculation with $r_0 > 0$. You will get the same $\vec k$ component of velocity. And you will also get $\vec i$ and $\vec j$ components.